# Windows 7 wireless not seeing any networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I think I have managed to confuse Windows 7. When I did the install, I had the network cable plugged in to my router, but the wireless card was also enabled. During the install, Windows 7 seemed to see my wireless network and even asked me for the WEP key. I know that it *used* the WEP key because I initially entered an invalid one and it gave me an error.

Then the network said "SoAndSoWireless Connected". However, when I unplug or disable my wired network card, then I have no internet, and it can't see any networks. When I plug in the wired network card, it says "SoAndSoWireless Connected".

Under Network and Internet > Network Connections I have "Local Area Connection" and "Wireless Network Connection". The wired one's status is "SoAndSoWireless" and the wireless status is "Not Connected".

Also, the wireless connection can't seem to see any other wireless networks in the area and I know there are tons. My neighbors have several.

I've somehow seemingly confused Windows 7 into thinking that my wired network card is my wireless card or something. Any ideas on how to un-confuse it?

This is a desktop machine by the way, if it matters.

EDIT:
Ah, I think part of the problem is that I named my *network* accidentally the same as the name of the wireless network being broadcast by the wireless router.  So that might be why it says that name on the hard-wired connection.  Perhaps the drivers just are completely not working for the wireless card.

Thanks,

~ Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out after much internet searching.  It turns out that I have a Linksys WMP300N wireless card which Windows 7 does not autodetect correctly with the right drivers.  I downloaded the drivers from Linksys, installed them, and then chose them specifically from the Device Manager for that device.  Then everything worked.

The additional confusion was caused by me accidentally naming my home network the same as the ID of my wireless network.  I renamed that to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a bit confused reading this...

Try opening up `Network and Sharing center`, then on the left, click `Manage Wireless Networks`.

From here, you should be able to edit the order, delete saved or add new Wireless networks.

[image]

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  But I figured it out it was a driver issue.